# Pathlib match() doesn't find a file with the same pattern, which can be found by glob()

Tags: python-3.x

I need both to collect files matching a pattern below a certain directory as well confirm that a file located in that directory (or in a subdirectory) matches that pattern. So basically I do this:

`Path('/foo').glob('bar/**/*.c')`

That returns '/foo/bar/file.c'. But if I try the other way:

`Path('/foo/bar/file.c').match('bar/**/*.c')`

I only get False back. It works if I remove the '**':

`Path('/foo/bar/file.c').match('bar/*.c')`

How do I get glob() and match() to behave the same without changing the pattern? I need it to work recursively.